# Making Intersection of 3 Lines Calculation More Efficient

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

So I managed to optimize the calculation a little for looking for 3 line intersections in equally spaced points around a circle by only checking one "wedge" of the circle, ignoring intersections on the mirror side, is there any way to make this faster? I really need this to work for 36 and then 38 points and as is they are faster than unoptimized but still slow.

[image: Left Fan]
[image: Right Fan]
[image: Criss Cross]
[image: Total Check]

```
num=36;
pts=CirclePoints[num];
tups=Line/@(Tuples[{Take[pts,1],Drop[pts,num/2]}]);
tups2=Line/@(Tuples[{Take[pts,-1],Drop[pts,-num/2]}]);
tups3=Line/@(Tuples[{Take[Drop[pts,1],Round[num/4]],Take[Drop[pts,-1],-Round[num/4]]}]);
intersections=RegionIntersection@@@Tuples[{tups,tups2,tups3}];
intersections2=RegionIntersection@@@(Flatten/@Tuples[{Subsets[tups3,{2}],Join[tups,tups2]}]);
Graphics[{{Thickness[0.0005],Join[tups,tups2,tups3]},{Directive[Red,PointSize[0.005]],Join[intersections,intersections2]}}]
```

Basically take a line from "tups1", take a line from "tups2", take a line from "tups3" and see if they intersect. By never picking more than one from either "tups1" or "tups2" I can eliminate choosing lines that never intersect since they share one point in common, "tups3" however does have intersecting lines so I have to make another list where I pick 2 lines from "tups3" and the last can come from "tups1" or "tups2". In the calculation for "tups3" I make sure to only draw lines that cross over the middle as a line that is drawn on the same side will never cross over the "wedge" that I am checking, so it doesn't need to be included in the check. Any kind of optimization further would be helpful.